# How to set up many to one relationship in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Let me preface by saying I'm pretty new to both Sitecore and C# so be gentle. I'm setting up products as Sitecore items for a new website we are working on. Each product could have dozens of replacement parts associated with it. Each part may or may not be associated with associated with multiple products. I'm trying to determine the best way to set this up taking into account creating and possibly reusing parts across products and also how best to associate parts with products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list Data Type like MultiList and Treelist (with Search) on the Product Template for the parts.

Avoid lots of items in a single folder this can give performance issues in the CMS. (up to 100 is okay). So create a tree structure for te parts if you have many parts, Or use a bucket. Bucket are good for many thousands of items.